# Crashlytics not working in android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I need help so that my app can run in version 4.4 or lower since I am doing the test in the emulator called nox player and it crested me taking the following log (attached file) as you can see it is a mistake in the library, I have installed the last version, here the line of my gradle compile

```
('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
         transitive = true;
     }
```

I also show you how I have my proguard file configured

you are with the lines

```
-keepattributes * Annotation *
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.crashlytics. ** {*; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics. **
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We support API 8 and higher. I saw your email into our support channel. The crash appears to be a crash from the app and not our SDK. It looks like you have a casting conflict in regards to the layouts you're using.

Comment: is that this block only appears in Android 4.4, I do not know the truth because if I take the sdk from the gradle, the app runs smoothly, you could guide me a little more please that could be generating this in this specific version ?, thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: sorry I could solve it thanks to your previous answer, I started to look at the generation options and if it was something of the start of the app, thank you. (Y)

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you can share your solution as an answer, that'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. I was able to overcame the issue by enabling Multidex support for android 4.4 target:
[Enable multidex for apps with over 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)